# MVC in Swift 4 - Model's interactions with Controller

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I'm developing a mobile application in Swift 4, that needs to interact with an external device using Bluetooth LE connection.

Currently i'm using the Model-View-Controller pattern to implement the structure of the app, but i need a clarification about.

When i receive data from the bluetooth adapter, i store it inside the model. The Model talks to the Controller "posting" the changes using the notification center.
On the other side, the Controller (the owner of the model) write the modification back to the Model simply setting the property of it.

The problem is that, sometimes, i do not have the Controller ready(instantiated), so i can loose Model's update (in that moment i'm not ready to "observe" the updates from the Model).

The only way that i found to workaround this issue is to:

1. In the Controller `viewDidLoad` read the status of the Model  using "getters" of the Model properties.
2. Register the Controller to observe the future Model updates.

This now is working fine, but what i would like to understand is if this is the correct behaviour of communication between a Model and a Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable for that model in the view controller.
For the variable, implement didSet and perform the operations that you want to perform in the view controller. You do not need to post the changes using notification center.
In viewDidLoad, you can get the data first time from the bluetooth adapter.
After that whenever you receive the updated data from the bluetooth adapter, update the model only. It will do the rest of the things for you.